# Data in view loads after second event in Angular5

Tags: angular, angular-promise, angular-httpclient

Hi I have upgraded my Angular2 application into Angular5 , I have used promises as well as observable in my rest calls(POST and GET) , It was working fine previously and it is currently working in most of my component ,but in one component all the data is fetched with single request but it is not showing in the view until next event is called. Any one have any Idea, I thought it was due to HTTP so I have changed it to HTTPClient still same issue araise. Here is the my promise code.

```
headers: HttpHeaders;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
if (AppConfig.getHttpHeader() !== null) {
  this.headers = AppConfig.getHttpHeader()
 };
}


getService(url: string): Promise<any> {
return this.http
  .get(url, {observe: 'response', headers:this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then(this.extractData)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}


postService(url: string, bodyParam: any): Promise<any> {
return this.http
  .post(url, bodyParam, {observe: 'response', headers:this.headers})
  .toPromise()
  .then()
  .catch(this.handleError);
}


extractData(res: HttpResponse<Object>) {
const body = res.body;
return body || {};
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
console.error('An error occurred', error);
return Promise.reject(error.message || error);

}
```

Comment: can you show the code for your component?

Comment: this._dataDiscoveryService.getService(this._dataDiscoveryService.queryUrl()).then(result => {
      this.savedQuery = result.data.map(businessQuery => businessQuery.query);
    });

Comment: where is this line executed? inside of ngOnInit? Please add the whole code of the component if possibe

Comment: I have written this code inside ngOnInit()

Comment: I have written following code in html       <div class="ds-taxonomy">
<ul class="savedQueryList"><li (click)='loadQuery($event)' *ngFor='let query of savedQuery'><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> {{query}}</li></ul></div> and following code in ngOnInit()  ngOnInit(): void {
 this._dataDiscoveryService.getService(this._dataDiscoveryService.queryUrl()).then(result => {
      this.savedQuery = result.data.map(businessQuery => businessQuery.query);
    });
    this.queryInformation=new QueryInformation("Taxonomies","Projections","WhereClause","sqlFunctions","GroupBy","Having","OrderBy");
  }